# How to create menu title that not related to any page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, posts

I want to display a custom menu title in the main page that is not a clickable link. I want to hover over the item and be able to click sub-menu items.

I am beginner so please forgive me for this stupid question.

Comment: You could add a "custom link" to the menu with `href` target to `#`. That way if you click you will stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the left WordPress Dashboard menu, hover over "Appearance".

Then click "Menus".

Select "Custom Links".

In the URL box, input: #
In the Link text box, input that title you want.
Click "Add to Menu".

That should do what you need :)